# Reference for recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Is there any good reference book, link or website for solving recurrence relation ?
Besides, is there any table for the type of particular solution for different kinds of RHS function of non-homogeneous linear recurrence relations when applying method of undetached coefficients?

Comment: Did you look at the Wikipedia article on recurrence relations?

Comment: Yes, I have read the article. Besides, I have read some files from Google. But I want to learn more about this topic in depth and want to see more examples.

Comment: For future reference please put the information in your comment into the question in the first place. Please visit the help center to get more guidance on "asking a good question"